# How can I only scroll a single nested component within a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf

I have a `ScrollViewer` which contains multiple `RichTextBox` elements which each have their vertical scrollbar visible. I would like to be able to scroll just *one* element at a time using the mouse wheel:

- If a `RichTextBox` has focus, scroll that
- Otherwise, scroll the `ScrollViewer`

Currently, if a `RichTextBox` has focus, both that *and* the `ScrollViewer` scroll. I believe that's because they both intercept `PreviewMouseWheel` - which means the `ScrollViewer` "sees" the event before the `RichTextBox`. That means I can't just mark the event as handled in the `RichTextBox`.

The repro XAML below has no codebehind beyond what's generated by default. (Obviously it looks terrible and my real app is *somewhat* nicer - but the essential "multiple scrollable elements within a parent `ScrollViewer`" is the same.)

```cs
<Window x:Class="RichTextBoxMouseWheel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <RichTextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="200" Width="400" FontSize="40">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 3</Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
            <RichTextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="200" Width="400" FontSize="40">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 3</Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

It appears like this:

[image: A window with two RichTextBoxes, one above the other]

... and behaves as described before - if a `RichTextBox` has focus, both that and the `ScrollViewer` scroll at the same time.

There's a reasonable argument to be made that this is simply bad UI design to start with, and I should avoid having nested scrollbars. I can *attempt* a fairly radical redesign to avoid that, but I'd rather not if there's a way to just make the existing design scroll as I'd like it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not `PreviewMouseWheel`, but the `MouseWheel` event.

You can fix the annoying behaviour by a derived control:

```
public class BetterRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really bizarre - I could have sworn it was using Preview from other experiments. But this does seem to work! (No need for a subclass either - just adding an event handler with `e.Handled=true` works fine, presumably because it happens after the RichTextBox handles it, but before it bubbles up.)

Comment: I'd prefer to have this encapsulated in the control, simply for not polluting your application code with a workaround for a misbehaviour of the control. IMO, RichTextBox should be doing this right in the first place.

Comment: As it happens, I'm already using a subclass in my actual app, so that I can bind the content XAML from a ViewModel. But it's good to know there are other options too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `RichTextBox` is not essential in your case, I'd suggest change it to the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. Then scrolling each `Scroll` works as expected

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Width="400"
                                  Height="200">
            <FlowDocument FontSize="40">
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 3</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Width="400"
                                  Height="200">
            <FlowDocument FontSize="40">
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 3</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

https://imgur.com/gzg52Nl

Comment: Unfortunately it really is important that these are editable :(

Comment: However, I'm intrigued as to how this works - if I can understand that, I might be able to apply the same thing to RichTextBox. What does FlowDocumentScrollViewer do that persuades the top-level ScrollViewer not to scroll?

Comment: i've replaced FlowDocumentScrollViewer with ScrollViewer and it still works as expected, so question is more about why ScrollViewer in RichtextBox behaves so weird?

Comment: I suspect (given the accepted answer) that RichTextBox bubbles up the event (doesn't mark it as handled) whereas other things do.